# develop screenshot chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i saw a lot of answers here but no one is what i'm looking for.
i want to take screenshot from chrome extension just for the screen i see at the first time without scrolling the page.
and "alert" the created file base64 path.

i have all the right permissions:

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "tabs" ,
  "storage",
  "unlimitedStorage",
  "browsingData",
  "notifications",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*",
  "file://*/*",
    "background" // added after i got the answer
],
 "background": { // added after i got the answer
    "scripts": [
        "js/background.js"
    ]
},
```

in my manifest.json

i also have the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("1");
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function (image) {
      alert("2"); 
    });
});
```

i got 1 all the time but 2 i never get and i don't know why. please help..

thanks ..

UPDATE

that's the missing part (background.js)

```
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
        null,
        {},
        function(dataUrl){
            sendResponse({imgSrc:dataUrl});
        }); //remember that captureVisibleTab() is a statement
    return true;
}
);
```

and then :

```
       chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function (image) {
      // alert("2");
            alert(response.imgSrc); 
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do extension API call in content script.Try to use use message passing if you really want to trigger this function in content script.

And please note that the permission requirement of tabs.captureVisibleTab() has been updated since chrome rev.246766.

> Extension need to have '< all_urls >' permission, or been granted the
>   'activeTab' permission to be allowed to use tabs.captureVisibleTab().

[Developer doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab) doesn't mention it.

manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs" ,
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "browsingData",
    "notifications",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "file://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"
]
```

Try to execute this code below in background page and screenshot capturing will work as expected.

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{},function(dataUri){
    console.log(dataUri);
});
```

screenshot

[image]

Comment: i got that message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'captureVisibleTab' of undefined

Comment: do you invoke captureVisibleTab in content script?

Comment: The problem is **not** the use of `<all_urls>`, but the fact that the API was used in a content script. Could you edit your answer to point that out, and not misleadingly suggest that the `<all_urls>` permission is needed for this API?

Comment: @Rob W, you're right, this problem is caused by making API call in content script. But it's a known issue (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339703) of captureVisibleTab API. Chrome team had released a revision to fix this issue and change the permission reuqirement of captureVisibleTab API. You could refer to this (https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=246766&view=revision) for more details. avishayhajbi had delcared " http://*/* " and " https://*/* " and this won't work for captureVisibleTab API. So I added the "all_urls" host permission.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does not work on Google pages as on the Extensions page, were it looks very natural to test your extension while developing.
(Should be a way to test that before taking the snapshot, I think...)