# How to get screenshot from chome.tabs.captureVisibleTab

Tags: javascript

I'm using simple js to take dataURI of an image using chrome tabs. I followed all the steps provided in the docs. But when I run and console it, it gives Cannot read property 'captureVisibleTab' of undefined error. What was the problem? Do I need to invoke any libraries? I have gone through many posts but none solved my problem.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "demo",
    "description": "my demo",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "sample.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
"content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
            ],
        "js": ["sample.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"       
        }
    ] 
  }
```

sample.html :

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
Hello...
  </body>
</html>
```

sample.js:

```
window.onload = function(){
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{},function(dataUrl)
    {
        console.log(dataUrl);
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098433/develop-screenshot-chrome-extension.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth  Whatever property I'm obtaining from chrome shows me an undefined error. And according to the link you have shared produces, Cannot read property 'onMessage' of undefined .

Comment: @GomathimeenaSubburayan were you able to resolve this?